# How to combine multiple columns after finding unique values in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

i have three columns R, S, T. I need to combine the unique values of column R, S and T by separating by comma and required result is in column U.

For this I have created formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA (UNIQUE({R2:R,S2:S}))
```

But it is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TOCOL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258)

```cpp
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(R2:T,1))
```

Comment: I was just going to same post.

Comment: But array is going outside in column u.

Comment: @RanjanKumarSingh, what do you mean?

Comment: Kindly visit https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gAuIXLm5_vApS5kc8QGYyXTlTwugP_Cvx44EmZx0U1c/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @RanjanKumarSingh, i don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: @RanjanKumarSingh Your sheet do not have any data.

Comment: The result in column U is getting HDFCBANK
ICICIBANK
KOTAKBANK
AXISBANK
INDUSINDBK
IDFCFIRSTB
BANDHANBNK

RBLBANK
CUB
FEDERALBNK but it would be as per pic attached with this question.

Comment: @Harun24hr data is in column R, S, T and U column

Comment: @RanjanKumarSingh Got it. Can explain what the issue with result. It seems getting unique values correctly.

Comment: The result in column U is getting HDFCBANK ICICIBANK KOTAKBANK AXISBANK INDUSINDBK IDFCFIRSTB BANDHANBNK RBLBANK CUB FEDERALBNK but it would be HDFCBANK ICICIBANK KOTAKBANK AXISBANK INDUSINDBK IDFCFIRSTB BANDHANBNK  FEDERALBNK RBLBANK CUB

Comment: @RanjanKumarSingh, are you talking about the order? Please clearly explain what the issue is. Highlight the cells that are returning the wrong result and explain what the right result should be.

Comment: Ya....the result is not in the requisite order.

Comment: I edited the answer to address this issue.

Comment: Giving in order but also count empty cell. It would be removed.

Comment: =unique(filter( UNIQUE(TOCOL(R2:T,1)),  UNIQUE(TOCOL(R2:T,1))<>"")) this one is works.